# Wise to run MS Velocity on my development machine?

Tags: asp.net, session, memory-management, distributed

I've never developed a web application that uses distributed memory.

Is it common practice to run a tool such as Microsoft [Velocity](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/) on my local machine as I develop, should I run Velocity on another server as I develop, or should I just develop as normal (default session & cache) and use Velocity only after I've deployed to our development server?

We are running into a lot of memory issues in our production web application so we are researching into splitting our servers into a farm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking at using Velocity on a project as well. What I've done thus far is to write a common caching interface and a simple implementation that utilizes the standard ASP.NET caching system. This way I can program against that interface and later plug in the Velocity caching via a concrete implementation of the interface. You can accomplish this more easily using a dependency injection framework such as Unity or Structure Map.

As for where to use Velocity, I'd be sure to try it out in a development environment before going live. If you have a limited number of physical machines, use Virtual PC to set up some virtual servers and install the caching framework onto them.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh that is some good feedback. I was thinking just the same thing about writing a common caching interface so I can switch out the default caching with Velocity without any code changes.

Based on an article by [Stephen Walther](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/08/27/asp-net-mvc-tip-39-use-the-velocity-distributed-cache.aspx), he appeared to be installing Velocity on his local development machine. So, that sounds like a good place to start.

In his article I was pleased to see that switching out the Session in the web server required no code changes... it was seamless ;)

I saw an interesting article on [Velocity's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/archive/2008/06/10/creating-multiple-velocity-instances-on-a-single-machine.aspx) this morning about installing multiple velocity instances on the same server. That way you don't necessarily have to use Virtual PCs.

I hope your project goes well.